# Gnome Shell Extension disables highlight?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-panel, extension

Zack here.  I have installed a gnome extension: [Panel Date Format](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3465/panel-date-format/).  I put in my settings and all that, and next thing I know, my clock no longer highlights when I hover over it.  It's not anything with my theme, because when I disable the extension, it highlights again.  Is there a way to mod the extension to make it highlight on hover again?  GNOME version is 40.4.  Thanks

Comment: There must be a way likely. Alternatively, file an issue to the extension developer.